# Automated way to flag a question for migration?

Tags: support, migration

What is the right way to indicate that a question should be migrated to a different site? It seems that the best option is to vote to close it or flag it and type in a comment suggesting the destination site. I'm surprised there isn't a more fill-the-form approach, so perhaps I'm missing something.

The question in question is [What is best way to represent polymorphic associations in relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11441716/145173), which should be moved to [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), as far as I can tell.

A related meta-question: What if this meta question belongs on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)? (I don't know how site-specific the flagging/closing workflows are). How would this question be flagged for migration? This related question isn't as important, but it's fun to ask a self-referential meta-question meta-question. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That post doesn't need migrating.

1. That question is **way too old** to be migrated; only questions < 60 days old can.
2. The question is not strictly off-topic here. Only migrate away posts that don't belong on Stack Overflow *at all*.

For a select number of sites (limited to 5) there already is the option to pick from a list, provided the question is not too old. For qualifying post, you'll find this list under the *Off-Topic* close option (look for the *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* entry). DBA.SE is currently part of that list.

For the rest, if the post is not too old, strictly off-topic here but very much on-topic on the target site (please do check their help center and do your research) and the post is of sufficient quality (i.e. you feel it is worthy of upvotes) then you can flag the post for moderator intervention and request a migration.

Of course, if the site *is* listed in the *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* option, you can select that when voting to close a post as off-topic.

Meta has no sites listed for community-voted migrations, so your only option is to flag a post and request a moderator do the migration. Your question is fine here, and should not be migrated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't know about the 60-day rule. That explains why the close options seemed confusing.